# Use order by clause in cross -object metadata relationship

Tags: custom-metadata

Is there a workaround to handle order-by in cross-Object metadata relationships?

So Here is the querry.

```
SELECT Id FROM Child__mdt ORDER BY Parent__r.Order__c ASC
```

where Parent and Child are the Custom Metadata types.

The error I get.

> UNKNOWN ERROR: INVALID_OPERATION: The requested operation is not yet
>   supported by this SObject storage type, contact salesforce.com support
>   for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can't sort via SOQL. The only "workaround" is the typical "implement a wrapper class that implements Comparable." For example, you could implement a variant of [this class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/95685), or [this class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/161180), or even just implementing your [own sorting algorithm](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/117965). Hopefully this will be implemented in a future release, but I couldn't find any Known Issues or Ideas related to that (please feel free to edit it in here if you find/submit something).